# Why does Lua display 4.0 instead of 4 when dividing 8 by 2?

Tags: lua, rounding

If I run `print(8 / 2)`, the [Lua demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) outputs `4.0`. If I then run `print(math.floor(8 / 2))`, it prints `4`. Why does Lua print the `.0` in the first example? All of `8`, `2`, and `4` should be quite easy to represent accurately in binary, so surely there shouldn't be any rounding issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua 5.3 distinguishes floats and integers: `5` and `5.0` are of different numeric types.

`tostring` for floats will always include a decimal `.` and `tostring` for integers will never include a decimal `.`.

The `/` operator is for float division; the `//` produces integers.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1

> Exponentiation and float division (`/`) always convert their operands to floats and the result is always a float. Exponentiation uses the ISO C function pow, so that it works for non-integer exponents too.
>
> Floor division (`//`) is a division that rounds the quotient towards minus infinity, that is, the floor of the division of its operands.